# Как извлечь имя переменной объекта или функции и преобразовать в строку?

Tags: javascript

Допустим у меня есть функция и объект:

```
a = function () {}
b = {}
```

Как можно извлечь имя переменной у
 объекта или функции и представить его как строку?

То есть что то вроде.

```
какая_то_волшебная_функция(a) = "a"
b.какой_то_волшебный_метод_или_функция" = "b"
```

Или что нибудь не такое волшебное, главное что бы получать имена переменных функций и/или объектов.

Comment: имя функции `a.name`, имя объекта `b.constructor.name`

Comment: Почему то не получается. a.name выводит "". b.constructor.name
выводит "Object"

Comment: Никак. ...........

Comment: @AlexeyTen, для функций - как.

Comment: Это будет собственное имя функции, а не имя переменной.  var c=a; что будет в c.name?

Comment: Опишите лучше задачу которую вы пытаетесь решить.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, забавно, но в заголовке спрашивается именно об _имени функции_ - так что все ок :)

Comment: @Grundy я на 99% уверен, что автор просто не понимает разницу

Comment: @AlexeyTen, очень может быть.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62123/discussion-between-grundy-and-alexey-ten).

Comment: Да я похоже не так сформулировал опрос. Мне нужна было как имя переменной в которой хранится функция или объект. Исправлю.

Comment: @АлексейAl, в общем случае это невозможно. Возможно у тебя [проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/186999). Опиши, зачем ты хочешь получить имена переменных.

Comment: В общем у меня есть массив который я хочу сохранять в local_storage по метке с именем объекта который сейчас активен. А потом когда вдруг тот же объект снова станет активным, загрузить его предыдущее состояние.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вывести *имя* можно **только** у функции.

Для этого у нее есть свойство [*name*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)

```js
a = function() {}

function b() {}

console.log('a.name =', a.name);
console.log('b.name =', b.name);
```

В остальных случаях получить имя переменной невозможно.